Meaning of _* in python (in reserved classes of identifiers)
The python documentation writes about _*
"Not imported by from module import *."
What do they mean with that?
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#:~:text=_*,import%20*.

The documentation uses * as a wildcard, meaning it substitutes for anything, similar to the way wildcards work in the shell. So when it says _*, it means any identifier beginning with _.
So when you do from module import *, it imports all the top-level names in the module except those that begin with _. When writing a module, you use _XXX names to create private variables/functions/classes.
